# Read a value from an XML file using java

Tags: java, xml

I can't read the branch number.

**XML:**

```
<NODE>   
 <EMPLOYEENUMBER EMPLOYEENUMBER="1334350"/>
 <BranchNumber BRANCHCUSTOMERNUMBER ="400823482"/>
 <BR AfterImage="51" BeforeImage=""/>
 <DEALNO="6698398" BeforeImage=""/>
 <SEQ AfterImage="0" BeforeImage=""/>
 <TRAD AfterImage="PHSS" BeforeImage=""/>
 <VDATE AfterImage="2017-04-07 00:00:00.0" BeforeImage=""/>
 <CUST AfterImage="10075222" BeforeImage=""/>
 <BROK AfterImage="" BeforeImage=""/>
 <BROKCCY AfterImage="UGX" BeforeImage=""/>
 <BROKAMT AfterImage="0.0000" BeforeImage=""/>
 <PHONCI AfterImage="0" BeforeImage=""/>
 <PORT AfterImage="CSPO" BeforeImage=""/>
 <COST AfterImage="30000003" BeforeImage=""/>
 <ODATE AfterImage="2017-03-02 00:00:00.0" BeforeImage=""/>
 <DEALDATE AfterImage="2017-03-02 00:00:00.0" BeforeImage=""/>
 <DEALTIME AfterImage="06:12" BeforeImage=""/>
 <IOPER AfterImage="RAMU" BeforeImage=""/>
 <VOPER AfterImage="RAMU" BeforeImage=""/>
 <BROKCDATE AfterImage="" BeforeImage=""/>
 <CUSTCDATE AfterImage="" BeforeImage=""/>
 <PHONECDATE AfterImage="" BeforeImage=""/>
 <DEALTEXT AfterImage="" BeforeImage=""/>
 <PHONETEXT AfterImage="" BeforeImage=""/>
 <PS AfterImage="S" BeforeImage=""/>
 <PRODCODE AfterImage="XYZ" BeforeImage=""/>    
</NODE>
```

**Java:**

```
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        System.out.println(" EMPLOYEENUMBER: " + eElement.getAttribute("EMPLOYEENUMBER"));
        System.out.println("BRANCHCUSTOMERNUMBER : " +  eElement.getAttribute("BRANCHCUSTOMERNUMBER"));
    }
}
```

If I read 'BRANCHCUSTOMERNUMBER' it's empty.

Comment: The output which you are getting is correct because in xml which you have shared there is no attribute which is having name as "BRANCHCUSTOMERNUMBER"

Answer (score -1):

You may try the below code.

```
import java.io.File;
public class ReadXMLFile {
public static void main(String argv[]) {
try {
File fXmlFile = new File("logs/file.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println("Main Tag:" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("SubTag");
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        System.out.println("Data 1 : "+ eElement.getAttribute("ElementTagName1"));
        System.out.println("Data 2: "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("ElementTagName2").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Data 2 : "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("ElementTagName3")                   .item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Data 4 : "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("ElementTagName4").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Data 5 : "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("ElementTagName5")   .item(0).getTextContent());
    }
 }
 } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}}}
```

Comment: 1) the tag names are irrelevant to the question. indeed, just copy-paste this piece of code with no explanation is really not helpful and 2) the code is formatted extremely bad

Comment: Yes Sharon,
Code is readable and understandable for a programmer, He can  modify as his need.  Sorry for the bad formatting. i just pasted it.

Comment: if the title is "You may try the below code" without ANY further exaplanation, then it is expected that the code will solve the problem "as is" but this is not the case. you could have make the small effort to adjust the code to the specific question. you could have make the small effort to expplain how is this irrelevant code going to help OP. you could have make the small effort to format the code. you did none. it took me more time to write this comment than for you to paste this "answer" . I only wish I could downvote twice.